# Program throws (Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xff' in file) when running from command prompt

Tags: python

Below is the code:

```
def add(a,b):
    return a + b
while True:
    try:
        a=float(input('Please enter a number'))
        break
    except:
        print ('Invalid Number, please re-enter')
while True:
    try:
        b=float(input('Please enter a number'))
        break
    except:
        print ('Invalid Number, please re-enter')
print(add(a,b))
```

Comment: I am a little confused by what you are trying to do.  Also, how are you calling this form the command line? just as a script with no parameters?

Comment: Works without error for me using command `python test_script.py`.

Comment: I run this in command prompt
 C:\Windows\System32> C:\application\app.py

Answer (score 8):

**Event:** Created a Python file via PowerShell; tried editing it in VS Code and got a similar error.
**Issue:** Powershell and VS Code encoding schema mismatch. *See*:
[Understanding file encoding in VS Code and PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/vscode/understanding-file-encoding?view=powershell-7.1)
**Resolution:** Recreated file using VS Code.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue may be how you are calling it form the command line.  You should change directories to where your python interpreter is and then point it to the script

```
c:\users\test>cd c:\python2.7
c:\python2.7>python.exe "c:\users\test\desktop\test_script.py"
```

Just use the path to your python exe and then replace my desktop with the path to your script.

Comment: Well i figured it out. I saved the file as UTF encoding before changing its extension from *.txt to *.py in my code. That solved it. Thanks - All.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your .py files are in utf-16 encoding. While running a python script (.py) file it should be in utf-8 encoding by default.

In my case:
I created a .py file using cmd/PowerShell prompt using

```
CMD prompt> echo #my First program > firstProgram.py
```

To fix the problem, open the file in notepad, select `save as` and change the encoding to utf-8 from utf-16.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to Stack Overflow.  While your answer appears correct, it conveys the same information as @Sukrit Jangwang 's answer.  Your post will be more valuable if you include information that is not already included in other answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the problem

### I solved it by changing the encoding of the file to utf-8

- Use windows 'notepad', click 'save as' then you'll notice the encoding section on the left of the save button. Select utf-8. then save the file.
- In 'notepad++' you can change the encoding directly in the program by the top section written 'encoding'. Change it to 'utf-8'
- Or in VSCode at the lowest bottom section on the right side, you'll see utf-8 or utf-16 or else. You can change encoding of the file there.

Like above comment said, I also created the file from PowerShell

- wsl touch filename will create utf-8 (wsl is linux on windows)
- echo "" > filename will create utf-16